# Python PyTorch Pyro - Multivariate Distributions

Tags: python, pytorch, pyro.ai

How does one sample a multivariate distribution in Pyro? I just want a `(M, N)` Beta distribution, but the following doesn't work:

```
impor torch
import pyro
with pyro.plate("theta_plate", M):
    theta = pyro.sample("theta",
                        pyro.distributions.Beta(concentration0=torch.ones(N),
                                                concentration1=torch.ones(N)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `to_event(n)` to declare depdent samples.

```py
import torch
import pyro
import pyro.distributions as dist

def model(N, M):
    with pyro.plate("theta_plate", M):
        theta = pyro.sample("theta", dist.Beta(torch.ones(N),1.).to_event(1))
    return theta


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(model(10,12).shape) # (10,12)
```

Answer (score 1):

For both PyTorch and Pyro distributions, the syntax is the same:

```py
import pyro.distributions as dist

samples = dist.Beta(2, 2).sample([200]) # Will draw 200 samples.
```

You shouldn't need to the plate notion unless if you're only wanting to sample a distribution.

Comment: I don't understand. I do want the plate notion to indicate that the $M$ draws from the $N$ dimensions are conditionally independent given the distribution's parameters. Isn't that precisely what plates are for?